# Scripting interplanetary transfers in KSP

Tags: kerbal-space-program

How do I find a maneuver node in KSP using the mod [kOS](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/) that represents an interplanetary transfer, for example from Kerbin to Eve?

I already know intuitively how to get a transfer, I just need help understanding how to code this.

Comment: I currently don't have time to write a full answer, but the gist is to solve [Lambert's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem) (which can also be used to yield [porkchop plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porkchop_plot)). After this you have to transform the obtained solar orbit at the SOI change points to the planetary escape trajectory (this might require some iterations since I believe the point where you leave the SOI can't be solved analytically) and from the planetary escape trajectory and initial orbit you can find the required change in velocity.

Comment: Can you help me write pseudocode for this? I have no idea what I'm doing with this to be honest... I know what I want to accomplish, and that's about it.

Comment: Mechjeb source code might be helpful.